# Exploring Layout Builder Challenges: Crafting a Puzzle-Style layout with Sidebars on Drupal 9-10 using Layout Builder

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

How can the Layout Builder be employed to craft a Drupal layout resembling the puzzle-style arrangement depicted in the image "Web 1920 – 1.jpg," where the sidebar operates as a region content managed by the Layout Builder? What particular challenges emerge in this scenario, distinct from the standard two or three-column layout conventions as illustrated in "Web 1920 – 2.jpg"?

My goal is to achieve the layout presented in [Web 1920 – 1.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tovSi.jpg), while maintaining the normal behaviour depicted in [Web 1920 – 2.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tYGB.jpg). It's noteworthy that I have separate region content and region sidebar, and I'm utilising Layout Builder for the region content layout.